# Malloc and free in functions (Optimizing your memory)

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

So i'm trying to optimize the managment of my memory in my code.

Here's a sample of the code :

```
    Image image;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    image = (Image) malloc(sizeof (struct image));

    image = doSomething(image);


    }

    Image doSomething(Image imageInput) {
    Image imageResult;

    imageResult = (Image) malloc(sizeof (struct image));

    //Code does something here 

    return imageResult;

    }
```

When is it proper to use the free(); in my example ?

```
Image image;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

image = (Image) malloc(sizeof (struct image));

image = doSomething(image);


 free(image);
}

Image doSomething(Image imageInput) {
Image imageResult;

imageResult = (Image) malloc(sizeof (struct image));

//Code does something here 

free(imageInput);
return imageResult;

}
```

The only time i can see is the "imageInput" variable that is supossed to be copied in the function and is suppose to be erased after the function ends.

Is it overkill to free a function variable ?

And at the end of the execution of the application too.

Comment: You *can't* `free` a function variable: you can only `free` memory that was allocated with the `malloc` family of functions. The function variables' life ends when you exit the function anyway.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: By (presumably) defining a pointer to your image as a type, you made it unclear exactly what you are allocating, and how much. `image = (Image) malloc(sizeof (struct image));` seems leery, since you have used `image` *and* `struct image` and it is unclear if you allocate only enough memory for a `pointer`. It is poor practice to define pointer types.

Comment: [typedef pointers is not a good idea](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware1/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=10506), especially if you don't show it.

Comment: After `image = doSomething(image);` since the function returns another pointer from `malloc`, you will not be able to free the original allocation - memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've used valgrind to analyze any memory leaks.

Pretty helpfull to guide someone into this task. Helped me to learn when to do a free() and where.

Here's a usefull link : 
[Valgrind website](http://valgrind.org/)